# How to combine 2 select elements together html

Tags: php, html, css, select, element

i am making a website and i want to combine 2 select elements togther. What i mean is to have a select option inside another. In the child select, the user may choose more that one option. 
This is what i mean (that doesnt work):

```
<select>
 <option value="1">
  <select>
   <option value="11">11 text</option>
   <option value="12">22 text</option>
  </select>
 </option>
 <option value="2">
  <select>
   <option value="21">21 text</option>
   <option value="22">22 text</option>
  </select>
 </option>
 <option value="3">
  <select>
   <option value="31">31 text</option>
   <option value="32">32 text</option>
  </select>
 </option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for your awnser,
nikoskon

Comment: How about an optgroup? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optgroup would look like this. Does this fit your needs?

```js
// '<value>': '<text>'
var group_members = {
  '1': {
    '11': '11',
    '12': '12',
  },
  '2': {
    '21': '21',
    '22': '22',
  },
  '3': {
    '31': '31',
    '32': '32',
  },
};

$('select[name=group]').on('change', function() {
  var $selectMember = $('select[name=group_member]');
  
  // clear options
  $selectMember.find('optgroup').remove();
  $selectMember.find('option').remove();
  
  // source here is 'group_members'
  // if you have much data i recommend using ajax here to query data by a script
  // as JSON have a look at AJAX - jQuery.ajax
  var selectedGroups = $(this).val();
  
  for(var i in selectedGroups) {
    var selectedGroup = selectedGroups[i];
    var optgroup = $('<optgroup>').attr('label', selectedGroup);
    
    for(var value in group_members[selectedGroup]) {
      optgroup
        .append(
          ($('<option>', { value: value })
            .text(group_members[selectedGroup][value]))
        );
    }
    $selectMember.append(optgroup);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Hold ctrl to select multiple
<hr />

Group:
<select name="group" multiple size=5>
  <option value=''>Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

Group Members:
<select name='group_member' size=5 multiple></select>
```

Comment: This would be good, only if i had a small selection of elements for each main option (1, 2, 3 in my example) but for what i need it, my selection is much bigger.

Comment: So you want to select with your first select box (eg. Car Manufacturers) and select in the second one depending on the first one (eg. Car-Models of selected Manufacturer)?

Comment: Yes! In your example I want to select ManufacturerX and also be able to select CarX, CarY ...

Comment: @nikoskon new solution added

Comment: It is almost perfect, the only thing that is missing is the ability to select more than 1 elements for both the Group and the Group Members. If it is not possible for the Group, thats ok, but i need to be able to select more than 1 in group Members. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @nikoskon got it, check it out :)

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whats your exact goal but there are some good select plugins that change the select in different ways.

https://select2.org/

I use the select2 plugin in most cases. Perhaps you can solve your problem with that plugin and you find and options you need.

Or another thing you can use are optgroups

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup